# How to use associated type protocol as argument's type to a function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

Here's the simplified code that I have:

```
class MyClass {
    func returnSomething(argument: Protocol2) {}
}

protocol Protocol2: Protocol1 where E == Int {
}

protocol Protocol1 {
    associatedtype E
    func doSomething(_ value: E)
}
```

Compiler gives me the following error: `Protocol 'Protocol2' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

I understand that associated type E needs to be resolved before the protocol can be used as an argument in a function, but given that Protocol2 provides that information, why I still cannot compile that code?

Comment: I think the correct syntax is `func returnSomething<T: Protocol2>(argument: T)`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since I am learning about Swift generics , so I want to give it a go:

If you want to use `Protocol2` as the type of argument in the function `returnSomething`

As suggested by @Nicolas Miari

```
class MyClass {
    func returnSomething<T: Protocol2>(argument: T) {}
}
```

Now as the name suggests this function should return something

so

```
class MyClass {
    func returnSomething<T: Protocol2>(argument: T) -> T {
            return argument
    }
}
```

Another issue that I see in the original problem is the use of `where` clause

I think you want to say the associated type of `Protocol1` is `Int`

you should do it like this

```
protocol Protocol2: Protocol1 {
      typealias E = Int

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how would you return an instance of a class that conforms to Protocol2? Instead just returning what was already passed in.

Comment: @damian I think you need to downcast to `T` so you can do something like this: `return ClassConformsToProto2() as! T`  and if you dont want to force downcast then you can do `return ClassConformsToProto2() as? T` and then change the return type to function as `T?`  you should remove your answer , as I think it is a separate question , it would be better that you ask a separate question, this way more people will be able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to use associated type protocol as argument's type to a function?"*

I might not be following what you're asking here, but if a protocol of yours have an associated type, e.g.

```
protocol DummyNumericTypeWrapper {
    associatedtype U: Numeric
    static func magic(_ bar: U) -> U
}
```

You can access this type e.g. in a generic context where the generic placeholder has been constrained to your protocol. To follow up the dummy wrapper above with an entirely dummy example, e.g.:

```
extension StupidNumericTypeWrapper where U == Int {
    static func magic(_ bar: Int) -> Int {
        return bar + 42
    }
}

func foo<T: StupidNumericTypeWrapper>(_ bar: T.U, _ _ : T.Type) -> T.U {
    return T.magic(bar) * T.magic(bar)
}

struct DefaultMagic: StupidNumericTypeWrapper { }

let num = foo(1, DefaultMagic.self)
print(num) // 1849  (43*43)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift compiler converted my `typealias` to the `where` clause. (Typealias overriding associated type 'E' from protocol 'Protocol1' is better expressed as same-type constraint on the protocol)

Passing argument indeed works with aforementioned syntax, thank you all!

But how would you return an instance that conforms to `Protocol2`?

```
class ClassConformsToProto2: Protocol2 {
    func doSomething(_ value: Int) {
}
}

class MyClass {
    func returnSomething<T: Protocol2>() -> T {
        return ClassConformsToProto2()
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work.

Cannot convert return expression of type 'ClasConformsToProto2' to return type 'T'